# How do I create a brush with default size on D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am having trouble understanding how brushes/extents work on D3 4.0. I wish to create a brush that I can drag along the Y axis of an svg element, and I want the brush to be already created upon the page loading, I don't want the user to have to drag along the g element to create it. (For example, this example has a brush that is created upon page loading http://bl.ocks.org/raffazizzi/3691274).

This is what I have so far:

```
var verticalRectangle = d3.select(".svgrectangle")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 500)
  .append("g")

var yBrush = d3.brushY()

verticalRectangle.append("g")
  .attr("class", "brush")
  .call(yBrush);
```

Right now this creates a rectangle which I can create brushes on by dragging inside it, I wish the brush to already be created on the rectangle on load (at the bottom of the rectangle with width of 100 and height of 10). I believe brush.extent() can be used for this, but I'm not sure what the correct argument would be on this case. Many of the examples use D3 3.0 and they use brushes with scales, which I believe is no longer necessary in 4.0 Thank for the help.

Comment: When you say _brush to already be created on the rectangle on load_ what do you mean? so like rather than beneath the projected sample, it appears on top of it?

Comment: I mean that the visible area that you can drag is already visible and ready to be dragged around. For example, in the example that I linked to the brush appears on the leftmost side of the graph without the user having to drag and create it first.

Answer (score 7):

I figured out how to do it. I have to call move on the brush and establish the area that I want my selection to encompass. For example -

```
var verticalRectangle = d3.select(".svgrectangle")  
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 500)
  .append("g")

var yBrush = d3.brushY()
  .extent([[0,0], [100,500]]) //Area you want your brush to be movable in
  .on("brush", brushed);

verticalRectangle.append("g")
  .attr("class", "brush")
  .call(yBrush)
  .call(yBrush.move, [5, 100]); //What area you want your brush selection to initially take
```